If manager points out others are being more productive, should I point out that they seem to be working more hours?
I started a new job recently. Another contractor started at the same time as me. It would seem that he's getting more work done. For example he frequently asks for more work and the number of tickets closed per day is higher than mine. The manager basically told me to work faster, and in private said he was surprised in the apparent difference between the number of tickets I close vs the other contractor.
How should I respond to this? Should I point out any of the below facts?

I don't actually know what the other contractor is being assigned. I think it's similar to me, but not identical. The manager isn't the one who assigns the work.

There is a fair amount of variability per ticket. Most tickets include instructions for one setup, but some cram 2 or 3 or more into one ticket.

I think the other contractor is working more than 8 hours per day. I say this because of the times I see him online. Also when he talks he says things like "I'll make sure to get all my tickets done by the end of the day" or "I have a lot to do today!". It had been my understanding we work for 8 hours, and if there are no tickets in our queue we should ask for more.



related: How do I maintain a work-life balance when company culture tends towards frequent overtime?

How many hours do you work per day compared to the hours that the others work per day ? Why can't you ask to work the same number of hours per day (8 hours per day) as others do ?

I am going to answer your question in reverse.
For starters - you ask if you should point out certain facts, but on examination - these do not appear to be facts, only presumptions - and as such, you should absolutely not point them out - because you simply dont know.
The first conversation that you need to have is around what the expectation(s) are for ticket closure rate.
Now, I dont know what sort of industry you are in, but let us assume a 1-3 month lead time on getting fully up-to-speed (as in, the time it takes to learn the infrastructure, learn the internal processes etc.).
In my own field of IT, I fully expect someone to be about 50% efficient in these first few months, rising steadily as they gain more knowledge about the aforementioned elements.
You want to be sure that you are avoiding comparison to this new peer. For example - If existing staff are averaging 8 tickets a day, and you are doing 6 within that 1-3 month period - I would say that is perfectly acceptable, even if your new colleague is doing 10 per day.
Some Managers can get a bit of a habit of if One employee can do X amount of work in a given day, then everyone should be able to do X amount of work in a given day.
Next would be to ask to do a ticket review with your Manager between the last X number of tickets and the same for your colleague - see what the type of problem or request was and see if it was a quick and easy fix or something long and complicated.
Also - see if there are any steps that are being done differently - so for example in my field of IT, some techs build their own troubleshooting scripts for common issues that help them diagnose faults quickly.
The key focus on this should be to answer the various questions:

Is there a disparity between ease of work that is being assigned
Are there areas that you could improve on or that your colleague is doing in a more efficient way
If you look at the total time logged for the tickets, you can probably also glean if they are working extra hours.

This leads you to one of the following scenarios:

It is luck of the draw with work complexity and you are getting some bad luck. This can happen, and it feels soul destroying when it feels like you are always getting lumped with the difficult tickets - but in the long-run it will even out (unless there is someone manually assigning tickets, in which case your Boss can have a chat with them to ensure a more even assignment)

There are areas where you could improve, in which case, take this onboard and try to be better.

Your colleague is indeed working more hours, in which case you want to compare tickets closed per hour between the two of you, rather than the total ticket amount. If your company pushes for unpaid overtime, remind them that they dont work for free and neither do you. If it is Paid Overtime and they simply want you to do more work - then politely decline and say you have other commitments (And never elaborate what they are)

Finally, and this is the one that hurts in the Ego the most - you could have been hired next to a Rockstar employee and they are just absolutely taking names and getting stuff Done. In which case, it happens and it can be disheartening - but so long as you are hitting the targets for an average (or even a bit above average...) employee, then that should be enough to get your manager off your back.



"these do not appear to be facts, only presumptions", I'm guessing you're referring to the point about the other contractor working more than 8 hours per day? I don't know if we're being assigned the same type of work - that's a fact. There's a lot of variability among my tickets - that's a fact.

@ClanLatin - Unless you have looked at their time sheets or looked at their pay slips and confirmed that they are working more hours, then you dont know - and levelling that kind of accusation without concrete proof is a bad idea. As I said - asking for a ticket review and comparing between yourself and the other person to gather that information is acceptable.

He now directly told me that he works more than 8 hours a day.

Being defensive won't win you any points. Like it or not, your co-workers are who you're evaluated against.  In some companies long hours are the norm... or terrifyingly productive people are... Or the focus isn't where you are assuming it to be.
Find a way to achieve more with your time., find a way to  squeeze in more time, or be prepared to find another job which better matches your expectations and abilities and availability.
You could try asking your manager whether they've noticed any areas where you could improve your efficiency.

Sometimes I have trouble knowing when to "act defensively". For example, maybe I should have pointed out more often to my manager when I didn't have tickets assigned to me for extended periods of time if he's going to be very concerned with the close count.

If your manager points something out, your first step should always be to carefully listen and understand why they are saying what they are saying. I would say that asking whether you should have requested more tickets, or whether there was some reason they weren't being assigned to you, is valid; that shows you are trying to understand what went wrong and fix it. If this was because you were assigned to other work that took your attention away from the tickets, it's worth asking how to prioritize. Don't defend, accept and learn. Unless the statement is incorrect, which is not true here.

Remember that your manager is not interested in attacking you. They're interested in making you a better employee. First fully understand what they are trying to tell you, and accept that they may be right, or at least that this is indeed their perception of what's going on. Then, if you think there is a misunderstanding, ask clarifying questions rather than challenging directly.


How should I respond to this?

If your working hours are currently filled fully with work, your work is proceeding at a normal pace in your experience, and there are no current hindrances, then I would simply respond that there are no problems currently visible to you.
It's unlikely you can make much more a response at this stage. I wouldn't be immediately drawn to speculate on why there is a significant difference between you and your colleague.
There are a variety of possible reasons. Some may reflect poorly on your colleague, such as corner-cutting. Some may reflect poorly on you comparatively, such as your colleague having higher skill or stronger and more specific experience. There's nothing you could do about this. Some may reflect vagaries of the work, such as the content of tickets or the work that happens to have fallen out of them. It may, like you say, come down to your colleague putting in overtime hours for the same pay, and you are not prepared to match that behaviour.
Most likely, your manager is simply comparing abstract statistics about the ticket rate, with no deeper understanding of the explanation for the difference, or whether anything can or should actually be done about the difference.
Often these statistics are just a way for a manager to pick a fight with staff who are unprepared to identify why the manager is being unreasonable.
